# How to tell if X.509 Certificate is Exportable?

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I have a simple C# DotNet console app that enumerates the certificates in a location/store.  It displays things like the following:

- x509.SerialNumber
- x509.Issuer
- x509.Subject
- x509.HasPrivateKey

Is there any property that will tell whether the Certificate is exportable?  I could not find one, but I am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a reliable way of doing it, because you have to cross the boundary from "implementation independent" to "implementation dependent" -- exportability isn't inherent to certificates or keys, but a function of how the key was stored.

If you're only on Windows, and you're on Windows XP or older, this will work fairly reliably:

```
try
{
    ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm key = cert.PrivateKey;

    if (key != null)
    {
        return key.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable;
    }
}
catch (CryptographicException) {}

return whateverYouWantUnknownToBe;
```

Once you're on Vista or newer then it's possible to get certificates where `HasPrivateKey` is true, but `PrivateKey` throws an "invalid provider specified" exception, to work around that you need to jump up to .NET 4.6.

```
// AllowExport says whether it can be exported in a PFX (encrypted key)
// AllowPlainTextExport says whether it can be exported as (e.g.) an RSAParameters structure
const CngExportPolicies RequiredPolicies = CngExportPolicies.AllowExport;

RSACng rsaCng = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() as RSACng;

if (rsaCng != null)
{
    return (rsaCng.Key.ExportPolicy & RequiredPolicies) == RequiredPolicies;
}

// Requires 4.6.1
ECDsaCng ecdsaCng = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey() as ECDsaCng;

if (ecdsaCng != null)
{
    return (ecdsaCng.Key.ExportPolicy & RequiredPolicies) == RequiredPolicies;
}

// Requires 4.6.2
DSACng dsaCng = cert.GetDSAPrivateKey() as DSACng;

if (dsaCng != null)
{
    return (dsaCng.Key.ExportPolicy & RequiredPolicies) == RequiredPolicies;
}

// previous code goes here.
```

But, ultimately, the only foolproof way is to actually try it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an RSA certificate you could do something like this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = cert.PrivateKey;
var isExportable = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable;
```